# How to get list of free_style jobs using xml REST api in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I want to get list of free_style jobs from remote Jenkins. 
eg. http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url,description]
by this i am able to get all jobs but i want to filter only freestyle project.

Answer (score 0):

Add a XPath filter for the `_class` attribute value, and wrap the results with a tag, e.g. `root`:

[http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url,description]&xpath=hudson/job[@_class="hudson.model.FreeStyleProject"]&wrapper=root](http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url,description]&xpath=hudson/job[@_class=%22hudson.model.FreeStyleProject%22]&wrapper=root)